# SQL, How do I add a column which needs to be a primary key, unique and auto-incrementing? Error says syntax error at or near "IDENTITY"

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE cities
(
    name varchar(80),
    location point
);

ALTER TABLE cities
    ADD city_id int IDENTITY(1,1) UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have followed documentation for a different RDBMS.

The correct Postgres syntax would be

```
alter table cities
add city_id int unique primary key not null generated by default as identity;
```